# React jwt login refresh issue

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, refresh

When I refresh web
it goes to root directory. so I tried to solve a few things
but it doesn't work

I really don't know why it happened please help me

app.js

```
const localStoragetokenCheck = localStorage.getItem('access_token');

useEffect(() => {
    if (localStoragetokenCheck) {
        dispatch(loginCheck());
        console.log('local', localStoragetokenCheck);
    }
});
```

user.js

```
export const LOGIN_CHECK = ' LOGIN_CHECK';
export const LOGOUT_CHECK = 'LOGOUT_CHECK';
   

 export const logoutClickevent = () => {
    console.log('logoutaction');
    return {
        type: LOGOUT_CHECK,
    };
};
export const loginCheck = () => {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_CHECK,
    };
};


    case LOGIN_CHECK:
            draft.logInDone = true;

            break;

        case LOGOUT_CHECK:
            draft.logInDone = false;
            break;
        default:
            return state;
```

Comment: At the root page, in a `useEffect` check if the user is logged in, if yes, redirects the page to where you want to go use the `history.push()` method, where `history` can be extracted from `react-router-dom` with `useHistory` hook.

Comment: Thanks bro It sovled my problem but How catn I keep my data ? when I click f5 do not go back to root, but it doesn't have data in Redux

Comment: @BlackMath Hey bro Thanks for you reply I fix the problem I used Redux-persist library so finally it works !